# Inverted Conditional for Passive sentences

Tags: conditionals, passive-voice, subject-verb-inversion

I was wondering what would the inverted version of a passive conditional sentence like the following ones be.

> If he were told to do so, he would tell me.
>
> If my car were stolen, I wouldn't report it.

Are the sentences bellow correct?

> Were he to be told to do so, he would tell me.
>
> Were my car to be stolen, I wouldn't report it.

Comment: Yes, but I'd stick with the originals.

Comment: That's a very archaic construction, practically Victorian. Native speakers might use it to appear fussy or as a joke, but not in ordinary speech or writing.

Comment: I belive that, in practice, most people would say "He would tell me if he was told to do so" and "I wouldn't report it if my car was stolen". Grammaticaly these constructions are a bit suspect but they are more colloquial than either of your forms.

Answer (score 1):

No. All you need to do is drop *if* and invert, not add *to be*:

> *If **he were** told to do so, he would tell me.*
>
> ***Were he*** told to do so, he would tell me.
>
> *If **my car were** stolen, I wouldn't report it.*
>
> ***Were my car*** stolen, I wouldn't report it.

<sub>See: [Wikipedia: English subjunctive—Inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Inversion)</sub>